# Why does `curl_getinfo` not return the expected data?

Tags: php, curl

I can't figure out why the content type of my curl request is not being set. I have reduced the problem to work in the console. I am probably just not understanding something.

```
php > $curl = curl_init();
php > var_dump( curl_getinfo($curl));
array(26) {
  ["url"]=>  string(0) ""
  ["content_type"]=>  NULL
  ["http_code"]=>  int(0)
  ["header_size"]=>  int(0)
  ["request_size"]=>  int(0)
  ["filetime"]=>  int(0)
  ["ssl_verify_result"]=>  int(0)
  ["redirect_count"]=>  int(0)
  ["total_time"]=>  float(0)
  ["namelookup_time"]=>  float(0)
  ["connect_time"]=>  float(0)
  ["pretransfer_time"]=>  float(0)
  ["size_upload"]=>  float(0)
  ["size_download"]=>  float(0)
  ["speed_download"]=>  float(0)
  ["speed_upload"]=>  float(0)
  ["download_content_length"]=>  float(-1)
  ["upload_content_length"]=>  float(-1)
  ["starttransfer_time"]=>  float(0)
  ["redirect_time"]=>  float(0)
  ["redirect_url"]=>  string(0) ""
  ["primary_ip"]=>  string(0) ""
  ["certinfo"]=>  array(0) {
  }
  ["primary_port"]=>  int(0)
  ["local_ip"]=>  string(0) ""
  ["local_port"]=>  int(0)
}
php > curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'));
php > var_dump( curl_getinfo($curl));
array(26) {
  ["url"]=>  string(0) ""
  ["content_type"]=>  NULL
  ["http_code"]=>  int(0)
  ["header_size"]=>  int(0)
  ["request_size"]=>  int(0)
  ["filetime"]=>  int(0)
  ["ssl_verify_result"]=>  int(0)
  ["redirect_count"]=>  int(0)
  ["total_time"]=>  float(0)
  ["namelookup_time"]=>  float(0)
  ["connect_time"]=>  float(0)
  ["pretransfer_time"]=>  float(0)
  ["size_upload"]=>  float(0)
  ["size_download"]=>  float(0)
  ["speed_download"]=>  float(0)
  ["speed_upload"]=>  float(0)
  ["download_content_length"]=>  float(-1)
  ["upload_content_length"]=>  float(-1)
  ["starttransfer_time"]=>  float(0)
  ["redirect_time"]=>  float(0)
  ["redirect_url"]=>  string(0) ""
  ["primary_ip"]=>  string(0) ""
  ["certinfo"]=>  array(0) {
  }
  ["primary_port"]=>  int(0)
  ["local_ip"]=>  string(0) ""
  ["local_port"]=>  int(0)
}
```

Does this only get populated once the request goes through?

Comment: yes, it becomes populated once the request goes through

Comment: @Ghost if you want to answer the question, I can give you the credit since your answer is correct.

Answer (score -1):

in PHP CLI you have to write statement in one line with semicolan saperated, otherwise scope of $curl is expired in next command execution

Also you dont have executed curl using `curl_exec($curl);`

```
php -r '$curl = curl_init("http://www.google.com");curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));curl_exec($curl); var_dump( curl_getinfo($curl));'
```

Comment: @mpyw, can you explain me how it is completely wrong, please read question proprely it seems he using CLI php >

Comment: `otherwise scope of $curl is expired in next command execution`  is wrong. It is preserved until halting interactive shell. In addition, `curl_setopt` and `curl_geninfo` should cause Notices(Undefined Variables) and Warnings(Type errors) if your answer is true.

Comment: Take back what you said. Try it.

Comment: Probably you are confusing between `php -a` and `php -r`. Questioner is using `php -a`.

Comment: @mpyw, Where questioner has mentioned `php -a` ?, dont try with your assumptions, thanks :)

Comment: Multiple lines which start with `php >` CLEARLY indicate `php -a`. Or you just want to quibble?

Answer (score -1):

Just call `curl_exec($curl)` before calling `curl_getinfo($curl)`.

Note that `"url"` may be different from the URL set by `CURLOPT_URL` when `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` is enabled. This is actually named as **`CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL`**: Last effective URL.

- [PHP Manual - curl_getinfo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php)

Unfortunately, you CANNOT retrive the very URL you set by `CURLOPT_URL`.